# How to calculate work with i and j?

Tags: physics

I don't understnad how to solve.  The problem is:

w = ( 2.0 N i - 0.6 N j ) X (-3 m i)

Is it supposed to be: (2.0N)(-3m) i - 0.6N J ?

Comment: Recall that ${\bf w} = {\bf F}\cdot{\bf s}$.  It's a *dot* product, so don't use $\times$ to denote this.  Your calculations from the 2nd line to the 3rd line is right.  Btw, For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: But the book says the answer is -6.0 J. I don't get how - My calculations say it's -6 Nm i - 0.6N j .

Comment: Oh!  I'm mistaken.  Please use $\rm\LaTeX$ for readability so that it's easier to follow.  Books can be wrong.  From the formula for work done, *dot* product has to be used.  Since $\bf i$ and $\bf j$ is *orthogonal*, their dot product is *zero*, so you only need the 1st component of $\bf F$.  This gives - 6.0 J

Comment: @GNUSupporter Also, I think the OP is confusing $\mathbf{j}$ and $J$.

Answer (score 2):

What the book asked you to calculate is apparently
$$
W = (2.0\mathrm N \hat\imath - 0.6\mathrm N \hat\jmath) \cdot (-3\mathrm m\hat\imath).
$$

What you calculated is
$$
\big((2.0\mathrm N \hat\imath) \cdot (-3\mathrm m\hat\imath)\big) - (0.6\mathrm N \hat\jmath).
$$

These are not the same thing.
An analogy would be if you were asked for
$(8 - 5) \cdot 3$ and you calculated $(8 \cdot 3) - 5$ instead; in that case
it is easy to work out the two results and see that they are different.

There is a shortcut we can take for the "dot" product in which we multiply only the terms that have matching unit vectors--that is, we multiply the $\hat\imath$ terms with each other and the $\hat\jmath$ terms with each other. But that shortcut only works if you multiply *all* terms,
$\hat\jmath$ as well as  $\hat\imath.$

Also, the "dot" product of two vectors is just a *number.*
For example, $2.0\hat\imath \cdot 3.0\hat\imath = 6.0.$
There should be no $\hat\imath$ or $\hat\jmath$ in your answer.

The fact that there doesn't appear to be a $\hat\jmath$ term in the "distance" vector in the question does not allow you to merely *copy* the $\hat\jmath$ term that you happen to see in the "force" vector.
It means that in order to apply the shortcut, you must write out *both* terms of the "distance" vector, either on paper or in your head, before you multiply. That is, you can write the formula like this:
$$
W = (2.0\mathrm N \hat\imath - 0.6\mathrm N \hat\jmath) \cdot (-3\mathrm m\hat\imath + 0\mathrm m \hat\jmath).
$$

So from the $\hat\imath$ terms we get the product 
$(2.0\mathrm N)(-3\mathrm m) = -6\mathrm J,$
because Newtons multiplied by meters are equal to Joules.
(The J in the book's answer is a symbol for the units, Joules, and has nothing to do with the vector $\hat\jmath.$)
For the $\hat\jmath$ term we have *zero,* because one of the terms is 
$0\mathrm m \hat\jmath$ and anything times zero is zero.
So the final answer is $6\mathrm J + 0\mathrm J = 6\mathrm J.$

---

By the way, one quick way to see that your original answer is wrong is to look at the units. Work has units of Newton-meters (Nm) or Joules (J),
and it doesn't have a direction.
Your proposed answer, 
$-6 \mathrm N\mathrm m \hat\imath - 0.6\mathrm N \hat\jmath,$
is an attempt to subtract something from something with different units;
it makes as much (or as little) sense as trying to subtract
$0.6$ meters from $6$ square meters, 
or $0.6$ meters from $6$ meters per second.
Your answer also is some kind of vector (because its components are multiples of $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$) when it should just be a number of Joules.